# Допустимо ли использовать кириллические ключи в массивах?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Допустимо ли хранить кириллические свойства прямо в ключах массивов?
Например так:

```
$array['Январь']['Вася']['Сумма']=100;
```

Или обязательно так:

```
$array[0]['name']='Вася';
$array[0]['month']='Январь';
$array[0]['sum']=100;
```

В первом случае проще получить сумму за весь месяц, и на мой взгляд, код проще читаем:

```
foreach($array['Январь'] as $arrayItem) {
   $sum+=$arrayItem['Сумма'];
}
```

Во втором случае код сложнее, появилась проверка на месяц, но не будет проблем с кириллицей:

```
foreach($array as $arrayItem) {
   if($arrayItem['month']=='Январь') {
      $sum+=$arrayItem['sum'];
   }  
}
```

Что я упускаю? Как делать правильно?

Comment: Попробовали? Работает?

Comment: Работает что для меня неожиданно - никогда не использовал :) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886573/non-english-characters-as-array-key-undefined-index

Comment: Работать то работает. Но насколько правильно так делать?

Comment: При работе в коде - не рекомендуется мешать языки. При сериализации/десериализации - сколько угодно.

Comment: @etki, пожалуйста, приведите пример, когда допустимо использовать.

Comment: Мне трудно сказать, но по ссылке в ответе переписка с "изготовителями" php, как я понял при беглом просмотре. Они дают добро :)

Comment: Если вам нужно вывести таблицу атрибутов товара, например "вес => 20 кг, размер упаковки => 1x1x1 метр", то всё это придет из базы данных, и вы даже не узнаете, что работаете с кириллицей. Однако писать пряямо в коде `$x['Январь'] = ...` будет не очень хорошо, потому что начнет перемешивать в коде английский и русский языки

Comment: @etki Спасибо! Пришло понимание, что использовать можно, но писать напрямую нежелательно. Вы сами каким вариантом пользуетесь?

Comment: `во втором... не будет проблем с кириллицей` - будут, у вас же строковый литерал с кириллицей в сравнении. (Ох уж этот некромант Дух Сообщества)

Comment: Открою для вас страшную тайну `class Вася { public static $январь = 'Январь'; } echo $январьВася = 'Январь Вася', Вася::$январь;` работает. Но я бы точно не стал так писать

Comment: Попробуй эмодзи - интересно будет ли с ними работать.

Answer (score -1):

Попробовал РНР 5.6

```
$a = array();
$a['Январь']=10;
print_r($a);
```

> Array ( [Январь] => 10 )

Comment: Насколько правильно так делать или это плохая идея?
Какие могут быть подводные камни?

Comment: Как написано по ссылке в комментах выше, это зависит от настроек локали (кодировок). Если код не планируется переносить или обновлять сервер/РНР - думаю, проблем быть не должно. Если же копировать код на другую кодировку, ожидать проблем стоит...

Answer (score -2):

Смотря какой кодировки документ.
Есть WIN1251 старые версии - в них лучше не мешать, т.к. могут произойти различные артефакты.
Если же использовать относительно нестарый PHP c UTF-8 - то можно, хоть за это в вас везде будут "тыкать пальцем", т.к. код станет менее Friendly